# How do I call the placeholder watermark in a class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I do this in an EditorTemplate View:

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
    new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

I now want to do something in a class file in which I am using TagBuilder and MergeAttribute. I use code, for example, to display an image for "required", and tried to modify it to do the same thing with placeholder. But I can't do `ViewData`. So this isn't working:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PlaceholderFor<T, TValue>
   (this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var placeholder = new ModelMetadata([CAN'T FIGURE OUT IN HERE]);
        placeholder.MergeAttribute([ALSO CAN'T FIGURE OUT IN HERE]);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(placeholder.ToString());
    }
```

I don't even know if the above would be appropriate so I could do something like this:

```
input.MergeAttribute += html.PlaceholderFor(expression);
```

or whether that is also the incorrect approach.

For context I am building an "input" using:

```
input.InnerHtml += html.EditorFor(expression);
```

Can any one provide a code example that would work in this context? Sorry if I am not explaining it correctly.

Comment: Are you trying to set the html5 placeholder of the input?

Comment: Yes. Was able to do that with `@Html.Textbox`. Trying now to do it in class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear about what you are trying exactly to achieve. But if you want to get the contents generated by the TextBox helper inside another custom helper you could simply call this TextBox helper:

```
public static IHtmlString MyHelperFor<T, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<T> html, 
    Expression<Func<T, TValue>> expression,
    object htmlAttributes
)
{
    var div = new TagBuilder("div");

    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var attributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
    attributes["placeholder"] = metadata.Watermark;

    div.InnerHtml = html.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes).ToHtmlString();

    return new HtmlString(div.ToString());
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.MyHelperFor(x => x.Test, new { @class = "foo" })
```

Comment: I'm doing this inside a helper already. I am trying to do `input.InnnerHtml += EditorFor(expression, attributes).ToHtmlString();` but it is not showing up. Am using `EditorFor` because I am rendering more than just textboxes.

Comment: @REMESQ, I don't understand what you are trying to do and what is not showing up. Also the standard `EditorFor` helper doesn't take `attributes` as second argument. It takes an expression as first argument and an optional second argument which represents the name of the template.

Comment: I was trying to get a placeholder into an `EditorFor` helper which has code to render regular textboxes along with radio button lists and check box lists. The helper is selecting the type of form element and is, therefore, generic. It may be just that I cannot do this. Thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: @REMESQ, how do you define a *placeholder* for a radio button? For a textbox it makes sense but for checkboxes and radio buttons I don't see how that would look like. Also what exactly are you trying to achieve? Write a custom EditorFor helper? Or use the EditorFor helper and inside the corresponding editor template use some custom helper? I really have hard time understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe if you provided a short example of how you would like to use the helper it would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: I recognize that the placeholder would appear in the radiobutton list but have no use. However, because it's a generic editor for all inputs I am limited. Just really polish on my finished app, and I can live without it. Thanks for helping out.